# Button event is not triggered from Listbox item template wpf

Tags: wpf, listbox, buttonclick, itemtemplate

Here is my xaml

```
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5"
                                       Text="{Binding Text}" />
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                                    Click="Remove">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding DeleteIcon}"
                                           Stretch="Fill"
                                           Height="15"
                                           Width="20" />
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

button event is not triggered in code behind or in viewmodel with command binding. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Trying this... It's work for me....

```
<ListBox Name="lstNumbers">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5"
                                       Text="{Binding Text}" />
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                                    Click="Remove">
                                <Button.Content>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding DeleteIcon}"
                                           Stretch="Fill"
                                           Height="15"
                                           Width="20" />
                                </Button.Content>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**`Cs Code:`**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Numbers> list = new List<Numbers>();
            list.Add(new Numbers() { Text ="1"});
            list.Add(new Numbers() { Text = "2" });
            lstNumbers.ItemsSource = list;
        }

        private void Remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public class Numbers
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: What change you made? in the button click i want to get the selected list item too

Comment: Xaml Code :<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"
                                    Click="Remove"  Tag="{Binding Text}" >. Cs  Code : private void Remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = ((Button)sender).Tag;
        }@GANI

Comment: it is not triggering the click event for me,

Comment: this listbox is in a user control, which is child of another user control, do you think is there any issue here?

Comment: THis is the error am getting   System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DeleteIcon' property not found on 'object' ''Student' (HashCode=11949699)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DeleteIcon; DataItem='ListBoxItem' (Name=''); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')